# How to generate custom tooltips in XPlot.GoogleCharts Treemap (F#)?

Tags: f#, tooltip, data-visualization, diagram, treemap

I want to generate a tooltip as described on the Google site (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap#tooltips),
and i cannot figure out how.

I took the example from https://fslab.org/XPlot/chart/google-treemap-chart.html and want to modify it, so that i have custom tooltips:

```
let tt = 
    Tooltip (
        //...

    )

let options =
    Options(
        title = "Treemap",
        minColor= "#009688",
        midColor= "#f7f7f7",
        maxColor= "#ee8100",
        headerHeight = 50,
        headerColor = "#9ebcda",
        fontColor = "black",
        tooltip = tt,
        showTooltips = true,
        showScale = true
)

data
|> Chart.Treemap
|> Chart.WithOptions options
|> Chart.WithLabels
    [
        "Location"
        "Parent"
        "Market trade volume (size)"
        "Market increase/decrease (color)"
]
|> Chart.Show
```

Comment: I don't believe you can with this library. This library allows for customisation of tooltips for normal chart types, but I don't believe it offers the ability to inject a custom javascript function for the `generateTooltip` option for Treemaps as described in that documentation. You could get hacky by generating inline html as described here (https://blog.leifbattermann.de/category/f/) then injecting it into a page where you write that js function manually... or use Fable if you want to get a bit more involved and need full customisation.

Comment: My current workaround is to extract the data via fsharp.data and then include it in a string (js-html-template), that i save as js/html file. Not as elegant as doing it directly in f#, but it works. Thanks for your hints, will have a look!